# Uniqueness of linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

Is there an energy functional or some other method which can prove the uniqueness of the system $$\rho_t+\varphi_x =0,  \qquad\varphi_t+\rho_x=\alpha \rho +\beta \varphi,$$
with initial and boundary conditions $$\rho(0,x)=0, \qquad  \varphi(0,x)=0, \\ \rho(t,0)=0, \qquad  \varphi(t,L)=0,$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants and $\rho, \, \varphi:[0,T]\times [0,L]\rightarrow \mathbb R$?  That is, show $\rho=\varphi=0$? I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Try to derive a PDE from this system then use the Energy method

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will give this a try.